# Proper way to update model when creating another model in MVC

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, model-view-controller

I'd like to know what is the proper way to update a model when creating another one who has a ref on the other model in MVC architecture.

For exemple :

I have a user account (user model) who contains an array of all my posts ID.

```js
user : {
  email : ...,
  username : ...,
  posts : [{type : Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref : 'Post'}],
}
```

And when I create a new post, I save the post in my PostController and after I don't know what is the best way to update the post's array of my user. Shoud I do it in PostController when I just created the post or shoud I create a new endpoint for my user and call after I've called my route to add my post?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: In the same call, you should create the post and update the user's posts array.

Comment: So in my PostController I should import my userModel and update my user? Isn't it bad in MVC pattern?

Comment: Well, actually that should be done by some kind of service. Controller is just responsible of handle the request and call a service that is who has the logic (create post and update user model)